# Picturebox Click-Event Bug Workaround?

Tags: c#, .net

I recently noticed that there's a strange behaviour handling Size and Click events of Controls like **PictureBox** and **Panel**.

**Max Width** and **Height** of them is limited by datatyp **ushort.MaxValue** while their click events are handled like **short** (So all clicks higher than 32767 will not be noticed)

Is there a way bypass this bug? (Without limiting maxWidth to short.MaxValue)

Comment: You need click on them? or just intercept mouse click? If second just use Win32 API

Comment: Unfortunately i need to know the click-Position on the control, i have a scrollable Panel with a Picturebox in it to show some measurement data and want to show by click the messurement data of selected position, so it would be nice to have as much place to draw the graph as large as possible

Comment: No control will display anything beyond 32k pixels anyway and for the same reason.. No workaround in WinForms.

Comment: At least a picturebox draws more than 32k pixels (at the moment testing with 40k pixels width, all pixels are drawn but the last 8k doesn't get their click event)
But it really seems there's no workaround, so i will have to limit maxWidth myself to avoid this behaviour

Comment: Actually there is one way: place FlowLayout, then add panels into each time when panel size more 32k, so you will have click position any way, just multiply recieved mouse position with panel number.